# Java exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, maven, exception

I'm trying to execute Maven -> Update project in Eclipse. Every time i do it i get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException".

If i look in the code there aren't any files marked with errors, neither the pom.xml.

Other people working on the same project don't have this problem.

What could be causing this? What details do you need to get an idea about this?

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace

Comment: ... it will be in the eclipse log file ...

Comment: A couple of things to check for:Does your Eclipse have the Maven plugin installed? If you imported the project does it have a maven nature; at a command prompt in the workspace where the pom is did you run mvn:eclipse eclipse? What about your settings.xml file, is it similar to your associates? This is in: Window -->Preferences --> Maven --> User Settings.

Comment: Richard: i have nothing in my error log file, this happens when doing Maven -> Update Project

Comment: Tony: I have the maven plugin, it has maven nature. The pom is in the root directory for the project. I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse but nothing happened. My settings.xml file is the default from maven.

Answer (score 1):

it looks you have problem with one of artifacts you have in local repository try to delete .m2 and clean install project again but you have to be connected to internet, if this not solving your issue check the version of maven you are using and compare it with others.

Comment: Hello, i tried deleting .m2 and downloading everything again when i did mvn clean install. I could compile the project successfully, however when i do Maven -> Update project i still get: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. In Project -> Properties -> Lifecycle i have "assembly:single" marked in red with "error"

Comment: is there any more description on this "assembly:single" ??, also it is better to share stack trace